# Plotting vector control interventions for Vector-borne diseases

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, systems-biology

```
(*Parameters and Initial Conditions*)
nh = 10000; (*Total number of hosts*)
nv = 20000; (*Total number of vectors*)

initialConditions = {sh[0] == nh - 0.0028*nh, ih[0] == 0.0028*nh, 
   rh[0] == 0, sv[0] == nv - 0.00057*nv, iv[0] == 0.00057*nv};

parameters = {a = 1,(*Mosquito biting rate per day*)
   bv = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected host to a \
susceptible vector*)
   bh = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected vector to a \
susceptible host*)uv = 0.25,(*Mortality/
   recruitment rate of the vector*)
   r = 0.167 (*Recovery rate from dengue in humans*)};

(*Differential equations*)
equations = {sh'[t] == -a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh, 
   ih'[t] == a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh - r*ih[t], rh'[t] == r*ih[t], 
   sv'[t] == uv*nv - a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*sv[t], 
   iv'[t] == a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*iv[t]};

(*Solve the system of differential equations*)
sol = NDSolve[{equations, initialConditions}, {sh, ih, rh, sv, 
   iv}, {t, 0, 90}];

(*Plot the results for the entire time range*)
Plot[Evaluate[{sh[t], ih[t], rh[t], sv[t], iv[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 90},
  PlotLegends -> {"SH", "IH", "RH", "SV", "IV"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, PlotLabel -> "Disease Dynamics"]
```

[image]

Now I want to change the number of susceptible vectors (Sv) and the number of infected vectors (Iv), both at timestep 15. We are multiplying the number in those states at that time point by 0.5, which means we are modeling an intervention with 50% efficacy at reducing the vector population in the community.

```
(*Parameters and Initial Conditions*)
nh = 10000; (*Total number of hosts*)
nv = 20000; (*Total number of vectors*)

initialConditions = {sh[0] == nh - 0.0028*nh, ih[0] == 0.0028*nh, 
   rh[0] == 0, sv[0] == nv - 0.00057*nv, iv[0] == 0.00057*nv};
parameters = {a = 1,(*Mosquito biting rate per day*)
   bv = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected host to a \
susceptible vector*)
   bh = 0.4,(*Probability of infection from an infected vector to a \
susceptible host*)uv = 0.25,(*Mortality/
   recruitment rate of the vector*)
   r = 0.167 (*Recovery rate from dengue in humans*)};
(*Differential equations*)
equations = {sh'[t] == -a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh,
   ih'[t] == a*bh*sh[t]*iv[t]/nh - r*ih[t],
   rh'[t] == r*ih[t],
   sv'[t] == uv*nv - a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*sv[t], 
   iv'[t] == a*bv*sv[t]*ih[t]/nh - uv*iv[t]};
```

Then I tried to solve again the differential equations with the new initial conditions as follows:

```
(*Define the time at which the intervention occurs*)
interventionTime = 15;

(*Apply the intervention by reducing Sv and Iv by 50% at \
interventionTime*)
solWithIntervention = 
  NDSolve[{equations, initialConditions, 
    WhenEvent[
     t == interventionTime, {sv[t] -> 0.5*sv[t], 
      iv[t] -> 0.5*iv[t]}]}, {sh, ih, rh, sv, iv}, {t, 0, 90}];

(*Plot the updated solution with intervention*)
Plot[Evaluate[{sh[t], ih[t], rh[t], sv[t], iv[t]} /. 
   solWithIntervention], {t, 0, 90}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Susceptible Humans", "Infected Humans", 
   "Recovered Humans)", "Susceptible Mosquitoes", 
   "Infected Mosquitoes"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Green}, {Dashed, 
    Red}, {Dashed, Blue}, {Dashed, Green}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Dengue intervention 2", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Number of hosts/vectors"}]
```

Then I have the following result
[image]

but I want something like the following. As we can see $S_v$ plots are quite different[image]

Comment: In `solPostintervention`, your initial condition is at `t==15` but you `NDSolve` from `{t, 0, 90}`.  You need to align those -- either make the ICs `t==0` or `NDSolve` from `{t, 15, 90}`.

Comment: @ChrisK Oh Thank you so much